# Add-Member : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a list of open ports and then using the PID to lookup `processname` and `username` via `get-username`, all packed into an array:

```
[array] $ports = get-nettcpconnection | 
    Select-object state, creationtime, localaddress, localport, owningprocess, remoteport, remoteaddress

foreach($i in $ports.owningprocess)
{
    Get-Process -Id $i -IncludeUserName | 
        Add-Member -inputobject $ports -NotePropertyMembers @{
            processname = $_.processname
            username = $_.username
        }
}
```

But I just get the following error:

```text
Add-Member : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:5 char:1
```

What am I doing wrong here? Or is there an entirely different and better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs because you're already explicitly binding `$ports` to `-InputObject` - PowerShell can only do one or the other.

Iterating over `$ports.OwningProcess` means you lose the reference to the individual `$port`, so you'll want to change the `foreach` loop to something like:

```
$ports = Get-NetTCPConnection |Select-Object State, CreationTime, LocalAddress, LocalPort, OwningProcess, RemotePort, RemoteAddress

foreach($port in $ports)
{
    # resolve owning process
    $process = Get-Process -Id $port.OwningProcess -IncludeUserName

    # add process details to $port
    $port |Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{
        ProcessName = $process.ProcessName
        UserName = $process.UserName
    }
}

# objects in $ports now have the ProcessName and UserName properties
$ports |Select-Object LocalPort,ProcessName,UserName
```

---

As an alternative approach, you could enumerate all processes immediately before invoking `Get-NetTCPConnection` and build a reference table you can use in a calculated property with `Select-Object`:

```
$OwnersByID = @{}
Get-Process -IncludeUserName |ForEach-Object { $OwnersByID[$_.Id -as [uint32]] = $_ }

$ports = Get-NetTCPConnection |Select-Object State, CreationTime, LocalAddress, LocalPort, OwningProcess, RemotePort, RemoteAddress,@{Name='ProcessName';Expression={$OwnersByID[$_.OwningProcess].Name}},@{Name='UserName';Expression={$OwnersByID[$_.OwningProcess].UserName}}
```